# How to extend com.sun.jsf.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I would like to extend the *com.sun.jsf.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder*. Where do I have to register such a class?

The reason is, I need to set a value (which is based on the bean which is being created) within the bean-to-create before the PostConstruct. So I would have to change the 
*com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build* method:

```
public Object build(InjectionProvider injectionProvider, FacesContext context) {
  Object bean = newBeanInstance();
  injectResources(bean, injectionProvider);
  buildBean(bean, context);
  if (bean instanceof SomeInterface == false) {
    invokePostConstruct(bean, injectionProvider);
  }
  return bean;
}
```

.. afterwards in *MyManagedBeanELResolver*'s revoleBean (registered in faces-config.xml as el-resolver) method:

```
result = manager.create(beanName, builder, facesContext);
if (result instanceof SomeInterface) {
  ((SomeInterface) result).setValue(...)
  builder.invoktePostConstruct(result);
}
```

Is there a better solution to it?

**UPDATE why I can't use the PhaseListener proposed by kolossus**
I cannot use the viewId to fetch the ManagedBean because I would like to have *n* types of Bean currently active, each accessed by their bean name.

I have a 1:n relation between viewId and ManagedBean, e.g. I have a *test.jsf* which has the backing-bean *TestBean*. It's also possible that a *TestBean0* exists which is the, lets say, a copy of *TestBean* but with a different value (which I need to inject, e.g. a "userId"). My *test.jsf* (together with a *ControllerBean* is able to determine which ManagedBean should be accessed, either the *TestBean* or *TestBean0*, which shows either the content from the *TestBean* (e.g. userId=27) or *TestBean_0* (e.g. userId=33).
This allows me to have the *1* view (*test.jsf*) with *n* models (*TestBean*) displayed at in the same page at the same time, e.g my test.html looks like this.

```
....
<h:outputText value="#{controllerBean.getBean('testBean', component).name}" />
<f:subview id="someId">
  <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/test.xhtml" />
</f:subview>
....
```

So therefore I can have a recursion (depth of the recursion is 1 in this case), where the outputText from the level 0 shows the name "Your userId is 27" and the included test.xhtml's outputText shows "Your userId is 33".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows (not exactly what I wanted, but until now I did not find a better way):

As I wasn't able to extend the *ManagedBeanBuilder* i decided to create my own BeanManager (*MyBeanManager*). It behaves equally as the *com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager*'s *getBeanFromScope* and *create* method, but a bit differently on *getBuilder*:

```
if (getRegisteredBeans() != null) {
  BeanBuilder builder = getRegisteredBeans().get(name);
  if (builder instanceof ManagedBeanBuilder) {
    builder = new MyManagedBeanBuilder(builder.getManagedBeanInfo());
  }
  return builder;
}
return null;
```

So i was able to inject *MyManagedBeanBuilder* and use my construct proposed above:

```
public Object build(InjectionProvider injectionProvider,
    FacesContext context) {
  Object bean = newBeanInstance();
  injectResources(bean, injectionProvider);
  buildBean(bean, context);
  if (bean instanceof SomeInterface == false) {
    invokePostConstruct(bean, injectionProvider);
  }
  return bean;
}
```

.. and in order to invoke *@PostConstruct* after i set the desired value into the bean, i had to override the *invokePostConstruct* to make it *public* instead of *protected*

```
public void invokePostConstruct(Object bean, InjectionProvider injectionProvider) {
  try {
    injectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(bean);
  } catch (InjectionProviderException ipe) {
    String message = MessageUtils.getExceptionMessageString(
    MessageUtils.MANAGED_BEAN_INJECTION_ERROR_ID,
    beanInfo.getName());
    throw new ManagedBeanCreationException(message, ipe);
  }
}
```

.. finally in *MyManagedBeanELResolver* I was able to set my desired value into the bean without having *@PostConstruct* called before. in *MyManagedBeanELResolver*:

```
if (result instanceof SomeInterface) {
  ((SomeInterface) result).setValue(value);
  ((MyManagedBeanBuilder) builder).invokePostConstruct(result, getInjectionProvider());
}
```